# Equivalents of Morris Kline's Calculus for Algebra, Geometry, Precalc...

Tags: book-recommendation

I started reading Morris Kline's "Calculus: An intuitive and Physical Approach" and I feel it's the book I've been waiting for since I started studying math.
I love his teaching style and the initially non-rigorous and intuitive approach to concepts.

I would love to find books similarly designed pedagogically for pretty much everything preceding Calculus, as well as for Stats/Probability, if such books exist. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You might like Freedman-Pisano-Purves's *Statistics* and Lockhart's *Measurement*.

Comment: @MariusKempe, Thank you and sorry for the late reply, I haven't logged in in a while. I'll check those out.